# Power BI, rule management (inner join)

Tags: join, powerbi, dax, inner-join, powerbi-desktop

I have to do in DAX this code, for simplicity I write it in SQL, practically I have to translate this SQL in DAX:

```sql
select 'id'
from x , y 
where x.client == y.client
```

I can't figure it out because I can't understand how to make this kind of join in using the DAX syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Power Query in Power BI you can make an inner join:

tbl1:
[image]

tbl2:
[image]

Script:

```
let
    Source = Table.Join(tbl1, {"client"}, tbl2, {"client"}, JoinKind.Inner)
in
    Source
```

Result:
[image]